# Regex Help (again)

Tags: c#, regex

I don't really know what to entitle this, but I need some help with regular expressions. Firstly, I want to clarify that I'm not trying to match HTML or XML, although it may look like it, it's not. The things below are part of a file format I use for a program I made to specify which details should be exported in that program. There is no hierarchy involved, just that each new line contains a 'tag':

```
<n>
```

This is matched with my program to find an enumeration, which tells my program to export the name value, anyway, I also have tags like this:

```
<adr:home>
```

This specifies the home address. I use the following regex:

```
<((?'TAG'.*):(?'SUBTAG'.*)?)?(\s+((\w+)=('|"")?(?'VALUE'.*[^'])('|"")?)?)?>
```

The problem is that the regex will split the adr:home tag fine, but fail to find the n tag because it lacks a colon, but when I add a ? or a *, it then doesn't split the adr:home and similar tags. Can anyone help? I'm sure it's only simple, it's just this is my first time at creating a regular expression. I'm working in C#, by the way.

Comment: what happens if you move the ':' into SUBTAG capture group. Like (?'SUBTAG':.*)?. Then you can strip the leading ':' from that capture group.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. It still returns the whole thing into the TAG group and leaves the SUBTAG group empty.

Comment: You need to make TAG group none greedo too, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this help

```
<((?'TAG'.*?)(?::(?'SUBTAG'.*))?)?(\s+((\w+)=('|"")?(?'VALUE'.*[^'])('|"")?)?)?>
```

I've wrapped the : capture into a non capturing group round subtag and made the tag capture non greedy

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what your aim is but try this:

```
(?><)(?'TAG'[^:\s>]*)(:(?'SUBTAG'[^\s>:]*))?(\s\w+=['"](?'VALUE'[^'"]*)['"])?(?>>)
```

I find [this site](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) extremely useful for testing C# regex expressions.

Comment: This doesn't work, what seems to be happening is that the program isn't reading up to the colon and simply puts everything in the tag group.

Comment: So like this? (Ignoring the second part of the regex).

Answer (score 0):

What if you put the colon as part of the second tag?

```
<((?'TAG'.*)(?':SUBTAG'.*)?)?(\s+((\w+)=('|"")?(?'VALUE'.*[^'])('|"")?)?)?>
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work. Are sure you put it right, the colon shouldn't be part of the group name, should it?